# Bitrise CLI - unsupported protocol scheme error

Tags: android, react-native, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, bitrise

I'm trying to run workflow locally for testing,
So I get the `bitrise.yml` file from the Bitrise dashboard.

So as in [secreats](https://devcenter.bitrise.io/bitrise-cli/secrets/) section, I add a `.bitrise.secrets.yml` file to set the secreat Env as they said

So after running

```
➜ bitrise run deploy-android
```

I got this error

```
Download keystore
Failed to download keystore, error: [Get "[REDACTED]": unsupported protocol scheme ""]
|                                                                              |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| x | sign-apk@1 (exit code: 1)                                     | 0.72 sec |
```

bitrise.yml

```
---
format_version: "11"
default_step_lib_source: "https://github.com/bitrise-io/bitrise-steplib.git"
project_type: react-native
trigger_map:
  - pull_request_source_branch: "*"
    workflow: primary
workflows:
  deploy-android:
    description: >.....
    steps:
      - activate-ssh-key@4:
          run_if: '{{getenv "SSH_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY" | ne ""}}'
      - git-clone@6: {}
      - script@1:
          title: Do anything with Script step
      - yarn@0:
          inputs:
            - command: install
      - install-missing-android-tools@3.0: {}
      - change-android-versioncode-and-versionname@1:
          inputs:
            - build_gradle_path: android/app/build.gradle
            - version_code_offset: "2"
            - new_version_name: '"1.0.1"'
      - android-build@1:
          inputs:
            - project_location: android
            - variant: release
            - module: app
            - build_type: aab
      - sign-apk@1:
          inputs:
            - use_apk_signer: "true"
      - deploy-to-bitrise-io@2: {}
      - google-play-deploy@3:
          inputs:
            - service_account_json_key_path: $SERVICE_ACCOUNT_GOOGLE_PLAY
            - track: production
            - package_name: com.myapp.pos
    envs:
      - opts:
          is_expand: false
        GRADLEW_PATH: android/gradlew
  app:
  envs:
    - BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_URL: $BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_URL
    - BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: $BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
    - BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_ALIAS: $BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_ALIAS
    - BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD: $BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD

    - opts:
        is_expand: false
      PROJECT_LOCATION: android
    - opts:
        is_expand: false
      MODULE: app
    - opts:
        is_expand: false
      VARIANT: release
    - opts:
        is_expand: false
      BITRISE_PROJECT_PATH: ios/orderApp.xcworkspace
    - opts:
        is_expand: false
      BITRISE_SCHEME: orderApp
    - opts:
        is_expand: false
      BITRISE_EXPORT_METHOD: app-store
meta:
  bitrise.io:
    machine_type_id: g2.4core
```

.bitrise.secrets.yml

```
envs:
  - BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_URL: android/app/my-upload-key.keystore
  - BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD: ******
  - BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_ALIAS: my-key-alias
  - BITRISEIO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE_PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD: ******
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/android-sign-apk-step-error-unsupported-protocol-scheme-fail-using-existing-release-keystore-file/5727/4) discussion on the bitrise.io, the solution was to specify the keystore url the following way:

> For local keystores provide file path url. (ex:
> file://PATH/TO/keystore.jks).

In my case though, I had to specify `file:///` instead of `file://`.